# End of the HunterXHunter

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I started watching HxH and I saw the video where Killua and Gon said goodbye. I haven't watched anime completely yet, but I am really interested
1) Did Killua leave Gon forever?
2) Did the 2011 series end like that?

Don't worry about spoiling me its fine I just want to prepare myself mentally :d

Comment: There is a website for HxH which details what happens per episode and what happens to each character during specific arcs: https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Hunterpedia You can find out the answer to this question just by reading episode summaries and character bios.

Comment: Did the show end? Yes. Is the series done? No.

Answer (score 1):

## SPOILER ALERT

I'll try to keep the amount of spoilers low and question specific.

---

> As shown, it is believed that Gon and Killua have parted ways but there is hope they'll meet in future because in the manga there isn't one instance of Killua or Gon after they part ways. It is all Dark Continent Arc after it and there will not be a specific Gon or Killua mention because they aren't included in the Arc as of now.

---

The 2011 series does not end like that, there is a whole lot to explore and a story to be built up.

Answer (score 0):

For the short time only kilua leave Gon to be able to steak with his father and but ging said enjoy some detour that come in your life..